# How to mock a Firebase set() with Sinon?

Tags: javascript, firebase, sinon

I am trying to test this Firebase access code

```
let writeHomePromise = admin
  .database()
  .ref(
    "sm_matches/" +
    match.date +
    "/" +
    match.homeTeam.name +
    "/homeNGSPlayers"
  )
  .set(match.homePlayers);
```

using Sinon.

I create a match with

```
    const match = {
        'date' : '2902199',
        'homeTeam' : '{"name" : "My_team"}',
        'homePlayers'  : ["Nomran Mailer", "Peter Bonetti"],
        'awayPlayers': ["Ernst Blofeld", "Postman Pat"],
      };
```

And I am trying, unsuccessfully, to mock that code with

```
    let refStub = sinon.stub();
    let setStub = sinon.stub();
    refStub.withArgs('sm_matches/2902199/My_team/homeNGSPlayers').returns(
        {push: () => ({key: 'fakeKey', set: setStub})}
        );
```

which gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`.

This is my first foray into Sinon, and even something this simple is giving me problems.

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Can you show the code where does `admin` come from?

Comment: `let admin = require("firebase-admin");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should call `admin.initializeApp()` before using any of the Firebase services. Below example using the [offline mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#offline-mode) testing strategy.

> Write siloed and offline unit tests with no side effects. This means that any method calls that interact with a Firebase product (e.g. writing to the database or creating a user) need to be stubbed. Using offline mode is generally not recommended if you have Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database functions, since it greatly increases the complexity of your test code.

Try stub methods like this:

`index.js`:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

function main() {
  const match = {
    date: '2902199',
    homeTeam: { name: 'My_team' },
    homePlayers: ['Nomran Mailer', 'Peter Bonetti'],
    awayPlayers: ['Ernst Blofeld', 'Postman Pat'],
  };
  return admin
    .database()
    .ref('sm_matches/' + match.date + '/' + match.homeTeam.name + '/homeNGSPlayers')
    .set(match.homePlayers);
}

module.exports = main;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

describe('71267791', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
    const databaseService = {
      ref: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      set: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const databaseStub = sinon.stub().returns(databaseService);

    Object.defineProperty(admin, 'database', { get: () => databaseStub });
    const main = require('./');
    await main();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(adminInitStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(admin.database);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(databaseService.ref, 'sm_matches/2902199/My_team/homeNGSPlayers');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(databaseService.set, ['Nomran Mailer', 'Peter Bonetti']);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
  71267791
    ✓ should pass (655ms)


  1 passing (661ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

package versions:

```json
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
```

Comment: Once again, an excellent, and compressive answer from you !!  Thank you ***very*** much. `Using offline mode is generally not recommended if you have Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database functions, since it greatly increases the complexity of your test code` - since I pay for each byte fetched or written,  I thought it better to stub all access. Am I wrong? I just inherited this project & have zero FB experience. If I don't pay for test mode, can you please give me a URL to the correct documentation to read? Thanks in advance